To need someone to do something
Auf Englisch (bzw. auf Spanisch) wird das Verb to need (bzw. necesitar) als gewöhnlichste Option bei der Übersetzung von brauchen verwendet. Das gilt reibungslos für die meisten Fälle, vor allem wenn das Verb ein Akkusativobjekt verlangt.
Das deutsche Verb brauchen jedoch eignet sich scheinbar überhaupt nicht für die Übersetzung gewisser syntaktischen Strukturen, die in anderen Sprachen durchaus möglich und normal sind. Konkret fällt es mir nämlich sehr schwer, eine passende Übersetzung für Fälle wie someone needs someone else to do something (bzw. alguien necesita que alguien haga algo) in seiner Gesamtheit zu finden, wo die Verwendung von brauchen auf Deutsch scheinbar einfach nicht geht.
Wie ich diesbezüglich beobachtet habe, werden solche Fälle gewöhnlich mit Mustern wie Folgenden übersetzt:

My mother needs you to tidy up your room. -> Meine Mutter möchte, dass du dein Zimmer aufräumst.
I need you to trust him. -> Du musst ihm vertrauen.

Ich habe vor allem Schwierigkeiten mit dieser Art von Übersetzungen, weil:
In 1. Bedürfnis in Wunsch umgewandelt wird.
In 2. das Bedürfnis des einen zum Bedürfnis des anderen wird.
Wörtliche Übersetzungen wie diese klingen für mich auf der anderen Seite sehr schlecht:

Meine Mutter braucht, dass du dein Zimmer aufräumst.
Ich brauche, dass du ihm vertraust.

Geht es einfach nicht anders mit brauchen? Ich möchte diese Indirektheit und Mischung aus Wünsch und Anforderung von to need am besten widerspiegeln. Würden an diesen Stellen andere Verben (wie benötigen?) besser passen? Vielleicht einfach andere Strukturen?

Du kannst das häufig mit dem Verb erwarten übersetzen.

My mother needs you to tidy up your room.
Meine Mutter erwartet, dass du dein Zimmer aufräumst.
Meine Mutter erwartet von dir, dein Zimmer aufzuräumen.


I need you to trust him.
Ich erwarte, dass du ihm vertraust.
Ich erwarte von dir, ihm zu vertrauen.


"erwarten" ist meiner Meinung nach nur dann stark genug, wenn "need" im übertragenen Sinne verwendet wird. Ein Satz wie "I need you to trust me" in einer Situation, wo es um Leib und Leben geht, sollte lauten "Du mußt mir vertrauen."

Als Ergänzung zu den Kommentaren zum Thema dass der Sprecher (Ich) ein Bedürfnis habe und nicht der angesprochene (du):
"To have a need" lässt sich im Deutschen mit "Ein Bedürfnis haben" übersetzen.
Du kannst bei "I need you to trust him." sagen, dass du ein Bedürfnis hast. "Ich habe das Bedürfnis, dass du ihm vertraust." Für mich als Deutschen fühlt sich das aber unnatürlich an.
Natürlicher mit nahezu gleicher Bedeutung wäre "Für mich ist es unablässlich/notwendig, dass du ihm vertraust."
Kommt das dem näher was du suchst?

Bei deinem anderen Beispiel geht das auch: Für meine Mutter ist es unablässlich/notwendig, dass du dein Zimmer aufräumst.

Generell gilt bei Übersetzungen: es ist unmöglich, vollkommen "identisch" zu übersetzen. Eine Sprache ist nicht nur ein Vehikel, mit dem Gedanken in Lautäußerungen übersetzt werden, sondern formt ihrerseits immer auch die Art, wie Gedanken entstehen und wie diese beschaffen sind. Zwischen Sprache und Denken besteht ein dialektisches Verhältnis.
Im ersten Beispiel wären auch andere Alternativen denkbar:

Meine Mutter verlangt, dass du dein Zimmer aufräumst.
Meine Mutter besteht darauf (sagt), daß du dein Zimmer aufzuräumen hast.

Im letzten Falle kann man natürlich einwenden, daß das "sagen" im Original nirgends steht, aber andererseits: wie hätte sie denn den Wunsch/die Aufforderung sonst zum Ausdruck gebracht? Schriftlich, auf Formblatt 08/15?
Das zweite Beispiel halte ich für einfacher:

I need you to trust him. -> Du musst ihm vertrauen.

Das ist insofern gerechtfertigt, als es die inhärente direkte Rede fortsetzt.
Einschub aufgrund des Kommentarwechsels (siehe unten):

das Bedürfnis des einen zum Bedürfnis des anderen wird.

Das sehe ich nicht so. Schließlich äußert derselbe Sprecher, der "I need you to..." sagt, auch die Aufforderung "du mußt ...". Der Satz drückt also ein Bedürfnis des Sprechers aus, weil er ja (halbwegs normale Umstände vorausgesetzt) den anderen zu nichts zwingen kann - schon gar nicht dazu, "Vertrauen zu haben", weil sich das nicht erzwingen läßt - und das "du mußt" lediglich als façon de parler dient. Siehe dazu auch die folgende Anmerkung.
Einschub Ende
Ob müssen hier durch etwas weniger Absolutes ersetzt werden sollte, ist fraglich, zB:

Ich mußte mir einfach die Haare färben.

Da wird ja auch nicht auf einen unabänderlichen Zwang abgestellt, sondern lediglich ein starker Wunsch zum Ausdruck gebracht. Dennoch könnten etwa:

Für mich ist es wichtig, daß du ihm vertraust.
Mir ist es wichtig, daß du ihm vertraust.
Ich will/verlange/bestehe darauf, daß du ihm vertraust.
Ohne daß du ihm vertraust, kommen wir nicht weiter.
Es ist erforderlich/notwendig, daß du ihm vertraust.

als Alternativen erwogen werden, abhängig vom Kontext, in dem der Satz geäußert wird.
Im übrigen: "brauchen" ist keineswegs die einzige Übersetzung für "to need":

This needs your attention. -> Das erfordert deine Aufmerksamkeit.


Mir ist selbstverständlich klar, dass Sprachen untereinander oft keine identischen Übersetzungen aufweisen, daher meine Frage.. : )Verlangen verhält sich tatsächlich wie eine Mischung aus Verlangen und Bedürfnis, es kann jedoch auch ein Bedürfnis ohne Verlangen bestehen.

@Sersovi: ...daher meine Antwort, die ja nach dem Satz noch weitergeht.

Beim 2. Beispiel bin ich noch völlig unzufrieden: I need you to trust him. -> Du musst ihm vertrauen.
Im Englischen hat der Sprecher "I" das Bedürfnis, im Deutschen dagegen der Angesprochene „du“. Aber Umschreibungen wie deine Vorschläge (mir ist es wichtig, dass..) könnten hier tatsächlich dem Original näher kommen. Danke!

Mir kommt allgemein nur etwas seltsam vor, dass es im Deutschen keine Möglichkeit für diese Ausdrucksform gibt (es geht nur einen Schritt über die derzeitige Verwendung von brauchen hinaus), besonders wenn man bedenkt, was für eine wichtige Rolle Modalität in dieser Sprache spielt.

Ich bin darauf nochmals eingegangen, denn ich glaube, Du siehst das falsch.
